# Sonar rule to catch raw collection types

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd

I recently introduced sonar to a large legacy project, originally written in java 1.3.

We have been gradually migrating code using raw collections etc to use generics. It would be nice to track our progress in sonar, but there does not seem to be an out of the box rule to catch raw collection use.

Is there an existing solution, or will I need to create a custom rule in pmd/checkstyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, because I would like our Sonar to catch this too:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

The rule that Dennis S mentions does not apply, since it is meant to catch the following situation (according to http://coding.tocea.com/java/gc_unchecked_type_in_generic_call/)

```
StringBuilder myText = new StringBuilder();
...
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean containsMyText = myList.contains(someText);
```

The code compiles because the `collection.contains()` method takes an Object parameter, even for typed collections. But it is an irrelevant check and will always return false, since the `myText` object has the wrong type and can never be added to the typed `myList`collection.

From what I have seen, it seems you would have to build a custom rule.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it does appear that nothing in sonar can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the rule you're looking for?

```
Bad practice - Unchecked type in generic call
```

This call to a generic collection method passes an argument while compile type Object where a specific type from the generic type parameters is expected. Thus, neither the standard Java type system nor static analysis can provide useful information on whether the object being passed as a parameter is of an appropriate type.

Repository : findbugs

Key : GC_UNCHECKED_TYPE_IN_GENERIC_CALL

Comment: I have this one enabled, but it doesn't trigger for code of the form ArrayList foo= new ArrayList();

Answer (score 0):

Hm, GC_UNCHECKED_TYPE_IN_GENERIC_CALL is now deprecated, and the suggested replacement, S2175 only checks if some of the Object-typed methods (i.e., remove(Object)) are called.

So, it seems that neither GC_UNCHECKED_TYPE_IN_GENERIC_CALL nor S2175 would issue a warning for, e.g., "HashMap x" as opposed to "HashMap x".

Seems strange that there seems to be no rule for this...